# Having trouble with a scrapy script (selecting links)

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, pycharm

I am using Scrapy and am having trouble with the script. It works fine with the shell:

`scrapy shell "www.redacted.com"` I use `response.xpath("//li[@a data-urltype()"]).extract`

I am able to scrape 200 or so links from the page.

Here is the code from the webpage I am trying to scrape:

```
<a data-urltype="/view" data-mce-href="http://www.redacted.aspx?ID=xxxxxxxxxx" data-linktype="external" href="http://www.redacted.com/Home/wfContent.aspx?xxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-val="http://www.redacted.gov/Home/wfContent.aspx?xxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">link text</a>
```

My problem is the script: (posted below) I know the `"a data-val"` is wrong.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import LinkscrapeItem


class Linkscrape(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lnkscrapespider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.redacted.com'


    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = LinkscrapeItem()
        links = response.xpath("a data-val").xpath.extract()

        for links in links:
            items['links'] = links

            yield{
                'links': links
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are going to scrape `data-val` from `a`. use below xpath.

```
  links = response.xpath("//li/a/@data-val").xpath.extract()
```

Comment: @DisplayName, great, you accept this answer, don't forget to click the check button. thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I am new around here, let me look for the button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.xpath()` twice:

```
links = response.xpath("//li/a/@data-val").extract()
# or
links = response.xpath("//li/a/@data-val").getall()
```

Also below doesn't make sense (may be you need `for link in links`? ):

```
for links in links:
    items['links'] = links

    yield{
        'links': links
    }
```